# Set Word 2010 document margins from C#

Tags: c#, office-interop, word-automation

I want to set the margins on a Word document I'm creating using automation from code in C#.

I've started the process using `ActiveDocument.TopMargin =` but I cannot find the C# code  similar to the vb `Word.InchesToPoint(.5)`  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes the simplest way works.  This line of code solved the problem

```
oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.TopMargin = (float)50;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the instance of the Word application:

```
Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.InchesToPoints((float)0.5);
```

See the reference :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff197549.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I followed the instructions but it did not work in C# got note saying best overloaded method match for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application.InchesToPoint(float) has some invalid arguements.

Comment: Did you try casting your value into a float. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Word Application object's InchesToPoints method like this:

```
        Word.Application wrdApplication = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document wrdDocument;
        wrdApplication.Visible = true;
        wrdDocument = wrdApplication.Documents.Add();
        wrdDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
        wrdDocument.PageSetup.TopMargin = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(0.5f);
        wrdDocument.PageSetup.BottomMargin = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(0.5f);
        wrdDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(0.5f);
        wrdDocument.PageSetup.RightMargin = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(0.5f);
```

Or if you like, you can make your own...

```
    private float InchesToPoints(float fInches)
    {
        return fInches * 72.0f;
    }
```

It could be used in something like this:

```
        Word.Application wrdApplication = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document wrdDocument;
        wrdDocument = wrdApplication.Documents.Add();
        wrdDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
        wrdDocument.PageSetup.TopMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5f); //half an inch in points
        wrdDocument.PageSetup.BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5f);
        wrdDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5f);
        wrdDocument.PageSetup.RightMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5f);
        wrdApplication.Visible = true;
```

Word uses 72 points per inch in its spacing.

Comment: You might consider explaining this answer a bit (e.g. 72 points per inch is the measurement).